# a null NSMutableDictionary that gets NSNumber

Tags: objective-c

on the init i have :

```
 dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; //dict is NSMutableDictionary
```

then i am adding him numbers:

```
[dict setObject:@"SPOT1" forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:array[0] ]] ;
[dict setObject:@"SPOT2" forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:array[1] ]] ;
[dict setObject:@"SPOT3" forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:array[2] ]] ;
[dict setObject:@"SPOT4" forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:array[3] ]] ;
[dict setObject:@"SPOT5" forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:array[4] ]] ;

NSLog(@"dictionary:%@",dict);
```

the `array[]` has a GOOD values.
the `NSLog`  print only the last spot5.(the rest of them lost)
and if am trying to send that `dict` (with this 1 value), with `NSNotificationCenter` i got it as null !
so it some how released.

why?

**edit for the NSNotificationCenter** :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DigitalArrived" object:nil userInfo:dict];//post

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(getSensorsData:) name:@"DigitalArrived" object:nil]; //get
```

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be `array` elements are all same. Pl. check that. If all are same, then value for the key will be replaced in the `NSDictionary` instead of adding new pair.

Comment: yes they are the same you right ! (its a digital word) so how would i do that when they are the same ? and why after sending them with the notification center, i got null ???

Comment: Can you pl. show ur code how you are posting the notification and how you are getting the dictionary from `userInfo` of the notification?

Comment: Fine, how you are extracting the `userInfo` from the notification?

Comment: GOT IT, i had a mistake, now i fixed it and it works. thanks!